# Dimension of a Component of a Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading about topological manifolds from *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu (Second Edition, page no. 48). He defines topological manifolds as follows.

**Definition 5.1.** A topological space $M$ is *locally Euclidean of dimension* $n$ if every point $p$ in $M$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that there is a homeomorphism $\phi$ from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. ... ...

**Definition 5.2.** A *topological manifold* is a Hausdorff, second countable, locally Euclidean space. It is said to be of *dimension* $n$ if it is locally Euclidean of dimension $n$.

In the next paragraph, he says,

> Of course, if a topological manifold has several connected components, it is possible for each
>   component to have a different dimension.

I understand what a component of a topological space is and also know that a component is connected as well as closed in it. But I don't understand what the **dimension of a component** is.

**My Question:** What is the definition of dimension of a component of a topological space? How can we determine the dimension? Can you provide a simple example to illustrate it?

Comment: Dimension of the component is the dimension of the open set in Euclidean space that the component is locally homeomorphic to.

Comment: It's defined in def.5.1 and def.5.2: consider e.g. the disjoint union of a circle and a sphere: the circle is locally one dimensional while the sphere is two dimensional.

Comment: @Berci that's the exact example I had in mind as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 5.1 the $n$ is part of the definition, so all points have neighbourhoods like open sets in $\Bbb R^n$.

In 5.2. the definition is more general: every point has its own local dimension $n(x)$, as it were, and then it's a simple theorem that in each connected component of $X$, the same $n$ is used for all its points. So in that definition a disjoint union of a circle and a sphere would be valid, and in 5.1 it wouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for explaining so clearly. I would like to request some clarifications though.
1. In the first sentence of your answer, does 'like' mean 'homeomorphic to'?
2.  Does 'every point has its own local dimension ()' mean every point $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n(x)}$?

Comment: 3. I don't see that Tu mentions about this theorem: "... ...in each connected component of $X$, the same $n$ is used for all its points". Am I missing something here? Also, where can I find the proof of this theorem?

Comment: @rainman yes, to the first 2 comments. The component fact is probably considered a general topology prerequisite? It follows from the open cover characterisation of connectedness, e.g.

Answer (score 3):

Dimension of the component is the dimension of the Euclidean space that the component is locally homeomorphic to, e.g. the disjoint union of a circle and sphere (one and two dimensional, respectively) or open disk and open ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (two and three dimensional, respectively).